# Identify similar Game to Achi

Tags: identify-this-game, ancient-board-games

We in childhood played game called Bead 12 and a smaller version with 3 Beads. It is called in our local language Bara Tehni or Teen Tehni. A Bangladesh version of this game also called Baroguti and with 16 beads it is called [Shologuti](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ae39/16d5563ac7f83265dae2f5afae5f0c89e8f2.pdf).
My main question is, Is there any variant of this game presented in literature? I know Achi is something similar to this game but Achi is more like tic tac toe, But in case of 3 Beads game main focus is to remove opponents bead from the board instead of making a row of our own beads. There is an Application on Google Playstore called Bead 12 which is the same game we use to play which says this game is played in South East Asia. So if other countries also play this game then what they call it? Why no information over internet? Am I missing the right keyword to search with?
Thanks

Comment: Can you reword your question? I am unsure what you are asking.

Comment: Some similar games to Bead 12 game. Or the right name of this game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Predominantly games of this style fall under either the **Alquerque** or **Zamma** families.

There are a number of variants played globally, with the board shape and number of stones varying considerably depending on region.
Games typically grouped in the Zamma family tend to have larger boards and stone counts, where Alquerque variants tend towards the smaller.
Though the grouping into families for this style of game is relatively arbitrary, and is mostly dependent on which game the individual doing the grouping first came into contact with.

As far as I can ascertain the 3 bead variant was developed by the Gujaratis, but as with a lot of these games there's no clear literature as to when the variant came into favor, or even of it's actual origin.

For similar games, the closest I'm aware of  in terms of board size would be *Four Field Kono* from Korea, but that has a modified capturing mechanism.
There are a number with almost identical rule-sets, so just searching for Alquerque is probably a good option.

Comment: Perfect. Alquerque!... That's what I was looking for. Thanks